# How to count related row in Table2 with associated key from Table1 with zero if not found - mysql?

Tags: mysql

There're 3 tables here `mb_branch`, `mb_item` and `mb_sell`. While mb* is from minibar.

1. I want to list all the branch name from `mb_branch` and count the item for each branch on date given. Let's say it's `2023-03-11`.
2. So I select all `br.name` from `mb_branch` and count all row from `mb_item` where `uid` related to each `br.uid`
3. I have 10 rows in `mb_branch` but only display 2 rows. Because there're item existed in the date given in 1.)
4. I want every `br.name` to display even there's no row existed in `mb_item` or show as 0.

Here is my code.

```
select
    br.*, br.name,
    count(it.id) as nit,
    sl.staff1 as st1,
    sl.staff2 as st2,
    sl.staff3 as st3,
    sl.money as money
from mb_branch br
left join mb_item it on it.uid=br.uid
left join mb_sell sl on sl.uid=br.uid
where date(it.dtime)=?
group by br.uid,date(it.dtime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a condition on the `it` table into your WHERE clause:

```
where date(it.dtime)=?
```

This eliminates out any outer-joined rows where `it` has no match, because if `it.dtime` is NULL, the condition of course fails.

If you want to limit the rows of an outer-joined table, put the condition in the `JOIN..ON`.

```
...
from mb_branch br
left join mb_item it on it.uid=br.uid and date(it.dtime)=?
left join mb_sell sl on sl.uid=br.uid
group by br.uid,date(it.dtime)
```